# Cannot log into GeoServer 2.19 with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7, geoserver, proxypass

I am able to reach the GeoServer log-in form on a new server instance using a URL like this: https://sub.domain.tld/geoserver.
However, entering the correct username and password causes **Cannot POST /geoserver/j_spring_security_check** to be displayed in plain text in the browser window and "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/j_spring_security_check" to appear on the address line (Chrome and Firefox).  Logging-in works just fine from http://sub.domain.tld:8080/geoserver and, while logged in that way, the SSL URL will skip the log-in form entirely and open the full GUI -- but none of the example layer previews will work (**Cannot GET /geoserver/tiger/wms** ...or whatever layer).

I have 3 similar servers set up with earlier software versions that all work perfectly:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Apache 2.4.6
Tomcat 9.0.4.0
JVM 1.8.0_171-b10 (Oracle) 
GeoServer 2.15.1 (also 2.14.1)
```

This latest server is:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Apache 2.4.6 
Tomcat 9.0.48.0
JVM 1.8.0_292-b10 (Red Hat)
GeoServer 2.19.1
```

I closely followed the GeoServer install procedure found [here](https://codepre.com/installing-apache-tomcat-9-and-geoserver-on-centos-7.html).  Apache was already installed and working with a virtual host configuration using certbot and a Let's Encrypt certificate.  I added the following to the <VirtualHost *:443> section of the */etc/httpd/sites-available/sub.domain.tld.conf* file:

```
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
  ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver

  <Location "/geoserver">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </Location>
```

I also set "https://sub.domain.tld/geoserver/" as the Proxy Base URL in GeoServer.  This is exactly how my working instances are set up.

The newest */opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml* file is slightly different in that it has separate CORS sections to be uncommented for Jetty vs. Tomcat.  The Tomcat section and the cross-origin filter-mapping are uncommented.    Unlike before, I had to enable the SELinux httpd_can_network_connect process in order to get to the GeoServer log-in form via SSL.  Disabling SELinux enforcement, however, does not solve the j_spring_security_check problem.

Sensitive WMS and WFS content must be served via SSL.  I am now spinning my wheels on research so any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any success on this issue? I'm facing the same problem. I can log in to GeoServer if I go to the server directly, but when I go via a Netscaler (proxy) setup HTTPS kicks in and I'm prompted with the same 'j_spring_security_check' as you.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem trying to reverse proxy a Geoserver docker container using Apache.

After bashing my head for a few days, I found I needed a couple of changes on both ends of the setup.

### Apache:

```
<Location "/geoserver">
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/geoserver
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/geoserver
</Location>
```

The `ProxyPreserveHost` directive should ensure that `sub.domain.tld` is what's used rather than `localhost`.

However, at this point I hit another problem, no matter what I did the login & logout URLs were using `http://` and **not** `https://`

This required adjusting the server config of Tomcat, specifically the scheme used by the connector.

### Tomcat:

```
<Connector 
 port="8080" 
 protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
 connectionTimeout="20000" 
 redirectPort="8443" 
 scheme="https"
/>
```

Note the value of `scheme` is `https`, normally it's `http` because it's the http connector.  This connector doesn't SSL/TLS encrypt the traffic so it would, under normal circumstances (appropriately), set the protocol to http.

Since we're using a proxy for SSL/TLS encryption we don't need Tomcat to do that work but we still need to tell Tomcat to describe the server name using https instead of the usual http.

Alternatively, you could also look at using the AJP connector which is an entirely different protocol but gets around some of these issues rather neatly and can be more performant.

The issue with this approach is that it requires more Apache mods to be enabled to work as well as some security concerns given how much more powerful AJP can be VS the http connector.

Also, there are some other proxy settings that can be used in Tomcat to possibly remove the need for ProxyPreserveHost in Apache, but this should get you where you're going.

---

**Additional reading:**

Tomcat HTTP Connector docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

Tomcat AJP docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html